# Random element from string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, random

I have a string array:

```
String[] fruits = {"Apple","Mango","Peach","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon","Tomato"};
```

and i am getting random element from this by:

```
String random = (fruits[new Random().nextInt(fruits.length)]);
```

now i want to get the number at which apple is present when i hit the button to get random fruit, like when i press randon button it gives me Banana..and also should give me that element number is `3`

I get the element but have problem getting the element number, so please help me out

Comment: when you say element number, you mean the index of the fruit in your array?

Comment: See also: [How to randomly pick an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just store the index generated in a variable, and then access the array using this varaible:

```
int idx = new Random().nextInt(fruits.length);
String random = (fruits[idx]);
```

---

P.S. I usually don't like generating new `Random` object per randoization - I prefer using a single `Random` in the program - and re-use it. It allows me to easily reproduce a problematic sequence if I later find any bug in the program.

According to this approach, I will have some variable `Random r` somewhere, and I will just use:

```
int idx = r.nextInt(fruits.length)
```

However, your approach is OK as well, but you might have hard time reproducing a specific sequence if you need to later on.

Comment: using generics, it drills down to `private static <T> T randomFrom(T... items) { return items[new Random().nextInt(items.length)]; }`