# Pulling individual strings from string arrays at random

Tags: android

Im trying to pull individual strings from a string array at random, and display it on screen(in android studio). But i cant seem to find a solution anywhere.
Its a simple string array, and i need to pull one at a click of a button. My string array is pretty standard and set up like this:

```
<string-array name="string_array1">
        <item>Sentence 1</item>
        <item>Sentence 2</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Use a regular array - plenty of solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array  -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340516/random-element-from-string-array

Comment: Can't find a solution for what? Just retrieve the array and then generate a random number for the index

Answer (score 0):

You can user java String array or ArrayList of String in Activity like:

Java String Array Example in Activity :

1)define an Array

```
 String string_array1[]={"Sentence 1","Sentence 2"};
```

**Get value from the array :**

```
Sting zeroIndexValue=string_array1[0];
Sting oneIndexValue=string_array1[1];
```

2) ArrayList Example:

define ArrayList of String:

```
ArrayList<String> string_List=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add value to List:

```
string_List.add("Sentence 1");
string_List.add("Sentence 2");
```

Get value from List:

```
string_List.get(0);
string_List.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch array from string file

```
String[] string_array1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array1);
```

Now generate random value and fetch it from array.

```
Random rand = new Random()
int Low = 0;
int High = string_array1.length-1;
int value = rand.nextInt(High-Low) + Low; //It will generate random number in the given range only.

String printed_value = string_array1[value];
```