# Illegal argument exception: n must be positive

Tags: java, exception, syntax, arguments

**main class:**

```
public class ECONAPP2 {
static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
static int score = 0;
static ArrayList<Integer> usedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    app();
    arrayContents();
}

public static void arrayContents() { 
    usedArray.add(2);
    usedArray.add(1);
}
```

**app() method:**

```
public static void app() {
    Random generator = new Random ();
    int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(usedArray.size());
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
    if (randomNumber == 2) {
        score();
        question2();
        usedArray.remove(2);
        app();
    }
    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        score();
        question1();                
        usedArray.remove(1);
        app();
    }
```

**getting this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:250)
at ECONAPP2.app(ECONAPP2.java:65)
at ECONAPP2.main(ECONAPP2.java:10)
```

can't work out what this means and what n is representative of ?

Comment: Read up on documentation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's failing for `size = 0`.

Comment: In this question, people forget 0 isn't positive.

Comment: what does this mean ?

Comment: @LeoRickayzen there are a few issues. Firstly, `usedArray.size()` is 0. This means that even if you found a work-around for the random generation, you would still get an error when attempting to remove elements. I believe you meant to call `arrayContents()` before calling `app()`.

Comment: @Obicere - You're positive of that?

Comment: @HotLicks it was a presumption. Minimal code was provided, so minimal insight can be attained.

Comment: @Obicere - I didn't mean to be negative.  In fact, I aught to know better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this line

```
int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(usedArray.size());
```

you are trying to generate random number.

However you have empty usedArray, so it returns 0. You cant generate random number in range 0 to 0 exlusive, so it throws exception. The value must be 1 or higher.

Note documentation : "value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)", so for example `generator.nextInt(1)` return 0 on all calls, `generator.nextInt(2)` returns 0 or 1...

Answer (score 1):

`n` represents the parameter of the [Random#nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method. The parameter must be a positive integer. In your example, the size of the array could be `0`, thus resulting in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the order you're calling methods in you main method.  Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    arrayContents();
    app();
}
```

This way when you call `app()`, your ArrayList has items in it.

Comment: This doesn't explain _why_ the list needs to have elements in it though.