# Random element choice from String array

Tags: java, random

```
public class Elements {
    public static String element_answer = "";
    public String[] elements = new String[118];
    elements[0] = "Hydrogen";
    elements[1] = "Helium";
    elements[2] = "Lithium";
    elements[3] = "Beryllium";
    elements[4] = "Boron";
    (...)
    elements[117] = "Ununoctium";
}
```

I would like to randomly choose a element out of the array and assign the random choice to the variable `element_answer`. How could this be done?

Comment: Sounds good but you haven't asked a question. Which part specifically are you stuck on? Have you searched how to get a random number in Java?

Comment: @codeMagic I added a question

Comment: This can't possibly compile?

Comment: @OskarKjellin I only added a small section because the real array has 118 entries (118 elements)

Comment: @user299824 Yes there's no need to show all items but i think it's better to post code that actually compiles (your still does not compile)

Comment: @user299824 Do you understand that *array number should start from 0*? I modified that in my pending edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to randomly pick an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
element_answer = elements[new Random().nextInt(elements.length)];
```

Comment: I then use p1_button1.setText(elementanswer); to assign it to the text of a button but nothing comes up on the button just NOTHING

Comment: I would argue that creating a `new Random()` every time you want to get a new random element will be costly in the long run. I prefer @chayasan 's answer more, where `random` can be stored as an instance field if need be to avoid over reconstructing.

Comment: @user299824 Look carefully.  You created an array with 113 null references.  Your odds of choosing one of those 113 nulls instead of one of the 5 are rather high.  I suggest you create your array a little differently.

Comment: @dsh OP have mentioned that all the 118 data have real entries in the comment section under the question itself.

Comment: @user299824 you have to post the entire activity for me to point out where you are missing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
Random random = new Random();
element_answer = elements[random.nextInt(elements.length)];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
import java.util.Collections;
[...]
Collection.shuffle(elements);
element_answer = elements[0];
```

It would do the trick. You shuffle the whole list and take the first one which is now some element out of this list. Randomized by the Java Collections.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your intention with my ESP (joke) that *A Class that returns a String which is randomly chosen from an array of Strings (which are names of chemical elements)*. If so, below is a possible implement.

Elements.java:

```
// The Class name of Java starts with upper case as normal
public class Elements {
    // There is no need of this field value.
    // public static String element_answer = "";

    public String[] elements = new String[118];

    // You need a random object
    private Random random = new Random();

    // Inside Constructor you can instantiate Strings in the Array
    public Elements() {
        // Array number starts from '0'.
        // This is quite basic knowledge. 
        elements[0] = "Hydrogen";
        elements[1] = "Helium";
        elements[2] = "Lithium";
        elements[3] = "Beryllium";
        elements[4] = "Boron";
        (...)
        elements[117] = "Ununoctium";
        // So array number starts from '0'
        // that the last number is [array length] - 1
    }

    // You need to define a method.
    // This is basic idea for Java Programmers!
    public String getElementRandom() {
        return elements[random.nextInt(elements.length)];
    }
}
```

Usage inside your `Activity` (or somewhere) is:

```
 // Declare at field
 Elements elements = new Elements();

 (...)

 // somewhere you want to use
 p1_button1.setText(elements.getElementRandom());
```