# Trying to figure out how to pull from an array and display it using JTextArea

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea

I'm trying to figure out how to pull from a list of questions and then output them using JTextArea. Right now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to randomly select from the list and then output it. This is what i have so far.

```
public static void Question()
  {
    String[] quest = {"place", "hold", "er"};
    int[] questNum = {1, 2, 3};


    JTextArea question = new JTextArea(6, 20);
    question.setText("Question " + questNum + quest);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly pick an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Why not do away with `questNum` and simply use `quest`'s index plus 1 wherever you need that?

Answer (score 0):

iterating array's and display in JTextArea

```
public static void Question()
  {
    String[] quest = {"place", "hold", "er"};
    int[] questNum = {1, 2, 3};

    String textContent = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < quest.length; i++) {
     textContent += quest[i] + " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < questNum.length; i++) {
     textContent += questNum[i] + " ";
    }

    JTextArea question = new JTextArea(6, 20);
    question.setText("Question " + textContent);
  }
```

Comment: I'd rather use `StringBuilder` than `String` in this case.

Comment: in this case, use of StringBuffer more preferable than String