# Math.random array length?

Tags: java

This is my code, for each array we have been asked to extract a value, to make a getter a math.random and a .length. I'm trying all but purtropo I can not go on. can I come? thank you all

```
public Integer [] year = {2010, 2008, 2018, 2015, 1994,};
```

(Edit: Here is the code. How can I create a random and a switch with 3 case?)

```
utility package;
import java.util.Random;
public class TavoloLavoro {
  private static Integer [] year = {2010, 2008, 2018, 2015, 1994,};
  private static string [] brand = {"Fiat", "Ford", "Ducati", "BMW", "Yhamaha"};
  private static integer [] displacement = {1200, 250, 1400, 1000, 600};
  Entire static private [] times = {2,4};
  private static integer [] ports = {5, 3};
  private static power supply [] power supply = {power supply.
  private static integer [] capacity = {1000, 2000, 3000};
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your requirements are. Can you explain them in more detail?

Comment: Do you have to select a random element out of that array? If so `Math.random()` and the array's `length` property are a good start. Do you understand what both do?

Comment: If I understand you, you want to select element from list with math random so try this, int var = (int)(Math.random()*year.length()); then use var and get your number from array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly pick an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065532/how-to-randomly-pick-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I understand that it may be difficult making oneself understood on an English language site. On the other hand, if you can’t, we probably can’t help you, very sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear, but as far is i understand you want to pick a random element out of your year array. 
BTW DON'T MAKE YOUR GLOBAL VARIABLES PUBLIC!!!

```
private Random random = new Random(); //u need to import java.util.Random
private int year[] = new int[]{2010, 2008, 2018, 2015, 1994}; //you had a comma behind the last element...

private int random_value_from_array = year[random.nextInt(year.length)];
```

Comment: A detail, Java accepts that superfluous comma after the last number.

Comment: @OleV.V. oh yea right. My bad.

Comment: That’s certainly OK. We still don’t know whether the asker intended that there or not. Your comment may still have been helpful.