# Comparing user integer-based input with variable in Java

Tags: java, android

### Edit #1

Someone in comments suggested using `Math.floor()` and `intValue()`. How to implement it to my code? Is it still possible to run the program on Android?

---

### What do I want to achieve?

I'm trying to create Android-compatible Java code (purpose is explained in comments in code). I'm new to Java, and still don't know about (probably basic) stuff like textboxes.

---

### What do I have?

Right now I have code that:

1. Generates `x` and `y` based on array-defined integer range (needs rework; explained in `What do I need?` below), and `z` (answer-equal variable) that will be used to compare input with actual answer.
2. Code comparing input (variable `answer`) with actual answer (variable `z`)

---

### What do I need?

Every needed piece of code is explained in comments in code, but here's a list too:

- Textbox (integer input), in which user has to put answer to x*y (which is equal to z). Input should be a variable 'answer'
- Code randomizing `x` and `y`, based on arrays

---

### Code

```java
public class numGen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] firstNum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
        int x = firstNum[/*Here program should put a random number out of firstNum array*/];
        int[] secondNum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
        int y = secondNum[/*Here program should put a random number out of secondNum array*/];
        int z = x*y;

        /*
         Here I'm looking to insert textbox (integer input), in which user has to put answer to x*y (which is equal to z). Input should be a variable 'answer'
         */

        /*
        And that's the code comparing textbox input with z variable:
        */

         if (answer == z);{
            System.out.println("Correct."); // and after good answer program should repeat with new x and y values...
             } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again."); // ...and here not.
               }

        System.out.println(x + " * " + y);

    }
}
```

---

Comment: For random numbers, try [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--). You can cast that Double to an Integer via `.intValue()`

Comment: @AustinSchäfer what should I edit in my code to implement `Math.random()` and `.intValue()` instead of the stuff I have in? And will the code still Android compatible?

Comment: Wait but the code you submitted is not an Android app.

Comment: @Titulum not yet. I'm gonna implement it as an activity later.

Comment: @Kaper365 the `Math` class is im the `java.lang` package. This means you basically cannot have Java without it. Assume that everything in `java.lang` is fair game everywhere you're using Java. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065554/6803997) for how to access a random index of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in android then you can not use main method, you need go for a single activity android app.
Particularly for your problems i.e .

> Here program should put a random number out of firstNum array
>   Use Random() object to get random int

same for other

> Here I'm looking to insert textbox (integer input), in which user has to put answer to x*y (which is equal to z). Input should be a variable 'answer'

For this you need a EditText and extract typed integer using 
`int answer = Integer.parseInt((editText.getText().toString()))`

Here is a complete solution with one activity.

MainActivity.java

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText textBox;
    private int z , answer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textBox=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        setActual();
    }

    // Top Part of your code from main method
    private void setActual(){
          Random random = new Random();

        int[] firstNum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        int x = firstNum[random.nextInt(firstNum.length)];/*Here program should put a random number out of firstNum array*/
        int[] secondNum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int y = secondNum[random.nextInt(secondNum.length)];/*Here program should put a random number out of secondNum array*/
         z = x*y;
    }

    // Cheking part of your code
    public void onCheck(View view){

        this.answer = Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());

        if(answer == z){
            // Do action on right ans
            Log.d("TAG","Correct.");
        }
        else{
            // do action on wrong ans
            Log.d("TAG","Incorrect. Try again.");
        }


    }


}
```

Here is xml for this activity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter you guess"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="onCheck"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```